# Unable to install Nativescript cli

Tags: node.js, npm, nativescript

I'm runninc the LTS version of Node on Windows 10
node --version v10.16.2
npm --version 6.9.0

cleaned cache --forced

npm i -g nativescript

When trying to install nativescript, I got following errors.
Tried this on 2 PC's with exact the same result

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\jacdir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\qr-image-329d9eb8\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\jacdir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\qr-image-329d9eb8\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\jacdir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\qr-image-329d9eb8\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\jacdir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\tslint-48178e6e\lib\verify\lines.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\jacdir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\tslint-48178e6e\lib\verify\lines.js
.....

npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="GitHub"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jacdir\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-10-03T09_22_49_068Z-debug.log

I don't have any errors when trying to install other npm modules

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason: In .npmrc there was a setting:

```
always-auth=true
```

After setting this to false, the issue was solved.
I hope this doesn't pose any site-effects